# Entity Framework never returns from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure that I call using EF:

```
try
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (var context = new SchoolDBEntities())
    {
        //to and from are datetimes, district is a string
        var courses = context.GetCoursesBySchool(from, to, district);

        foreach (var cs in courses)
        { sb.Append(cs); }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error Message: " + ex.Message);
}
```

The issue is that if I pass in a small enough date range; district is always required, I am getting data back as expected. However, if make the date range for example a year or possibly more, or even make them null; SP knows to ignore the dates if null, the SP never seems to return back any results. In fact the console writeline that is next line of execution after the foreach loop is never even hit. The code never falls into the CATCH block either in this case. I suspected that an exception was being thrown because a large amount of the data was being returned, but since the CATCH is not being hit I am not sure what is happening.

I saw a lot of suggestions where people I have suggested that you need to set your timeout for EF, because it is probably elapses, but in this case you would think that the CATCH block would be hit at least and it is not indicating a timeout from EF to SQL. I suspect that perhaps that if a timeout is happening and it is related to a performance issue with the SP could be occurring, but that does not make much sense I have tested this SP in SQL management studio with many date ranges; small and large, and the SP is running very efficiently; under 10 seconds for several thousand records in all cases.

Here is my QUESTION:

Is it possible that a first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll that could immediately close the connection and not move the code onto the next line of execution?

Any suggestions are welcome, but please respectful and I apologize in advance if I am missing something painfully obvious.

Comment: Give us called code too: both GetCoursesBySchool method and stored procedure :) From now it's really hard to say what's wrong with it

Comment: I do not think there is a timeout going now. The call using EF to the stored procedure takes less than 10 seconds and I can verify in the database that all the updates that take place before the data is returned, are being committed. It is almost like EF is choking on consuming a large amount of data.